# Magento 2.3 - event when catalog price rules are applied

Tags: event-observer, catalog-price-rules, indexer, magento2.3, catalog-rules

I am working in a module which extends **catalogrule** feature

In this module, we apply some changes to price calculation process. Right now, it is working when a product is saved in admin. We have achieved that by rewriting some classes in **Magento/CatalogRule/Model/Indexer** folder [Magento2 catalogrule promotions, ability to choose price or special_price?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250176/magento2-catalogrule-promotions-ability-to-choose-price-or-special-price/253655#253655)

The pending thing is: module code are not being executed when applying rules in admin. I was thinking to observe `catalogrule_apply_all` event, but I am not sure if it still exists in Magento 2.3

The only reference for that event I have found is in **vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Job.php** class

```
/**
 * Dispatch event "catalogrule_apply_all" and set success or error message depends on result
 *
 * @return \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Job
 * @api
 */
public function applyAll()
{
    try {
        $this->ruleProcessor->markIndexerAsInvalid();
        $this->setSuccess(__('Updated rules applied.'));
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->setError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But that `markIndexerAsInvalid()` function doesn't seem to fire any event. It just seem to invalidate related index

Any tips? Which code is fired when applying catalog rules in admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, at least in **2.3** version, that event `catalogrule_apply_all` is not being used (nor fired) any more

As index management in **Magento2** is reserved to cron it makes sense just flagging the relevant index as invalid, so next cron execution will reindex & do what was done in `catalogrule_apply_all` event