# Magento 2 How to Catalog Price rule apply on product special price

Tags: magento2.3.1, catalog-price-rules, special-price

i want to **catalog price rule** apply on `special price` product but i see in *magento default apply* only on product `final price`

[image]

but i want to catalog rule apply on product special price

how can achieve this? anyone help me on this case

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I used to use [This solutions from another Stack Exchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250176/magento2-catalogrule-promotions-ability-to-choose-price-or-special-price), but it's not working any more.

Answer (score 0):

I can't create a new comment, but I've been through the [link I posted earlier](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250176/magento2-catalogrule-promotions-ability-to-choose-price-or-special-price) and fixed the issue. I had to replace $storeId by \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID in the joinLeft call.

Comment: Thanks for replay can you share your module here? or Github